# PivotTableWizard using connection

Tags: c#, excel, vb.net, pivot, connection-string

I´m having trouble trying to use the parameter "connection" from the method `PivotTableWizard()`.

Could someone explain me the proper way to use it?

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/excel-vba/articles/worksheet-pivottablewizard-method-excel#

Comment: I would like some kind of example of its use.